# NullPointerExceprion at recursive method

Tags: java, recursion, nullpointerexception

I have this recursive method:

```
 public Hund getMor(int id) {
    Hund barn = getHund(id);
    int idMor = barn.getId_mor();
    Hund mor = getHund(idMor);

    return mor;
}

public String getMorTre(int id) {
    if (id == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    if (!existHund(id)) {
        return "Hunden du søkte etter finnes ikke";
    } else {
        if (id == 0) {
            return null;
        } else {
            Hund mor = getMor(id);
            MinRamme.jta.append(mor.toString() + "\n");
            int morId = mor.getId();
            return getMorTre(morId);
        }

    }
}
```

I have tried to remove the nullpointer by returning null if the id is 0 but this does not work. Does anyone have a solution?

NPE:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue -0" java.lang.nullpointerexception
at Arkiv.getMorTre(Arkiv.java:209)
at Arkiv.getMorTre(Arkiv.java:211)
at Arkiv.getMorTre(Arkiv.java:211)
at MinRamme$4.actionPerformed(MinRamme.java:89) <37 internal calls>
```

Comment: Please include the exception. What line gives the error?

Comment: On what line do you get the NPE?

Comment: We don't know what's throwing the exception. Please post a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Where are you getting the NPE? What line of code?

Comment: You need to add more details, like where do you get the null pointer exception, the code for getMother method.

Comment: look into the stack trace of the `NullPointerException` you get and see where it's thrown (and maybe post the stack trace as well). My guess is that `getMother(id)` returns `null`, but without the stack trace who knows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Where does the NullPointerException occur? That would help... That being said:

Inside your else clause, your

```
if (id==0) {
```

is useless, since you're testing that at the beginning and the id isn't changed.

I think you need to check if

```
getMother(id)
```

returns null, that is probably where you're getting the NullPointer... but you could confirm that now, couldn't you?

Comment: Thank you, checked if the getMother(id) == null and it made the NPE go away!

Answer (score 2):

It is likely (but difficult to confirm until you let us know what line is throwing the NPE) that the line that generates the NPE is

```
MyFrame.jta.append(mother.toString() + "\n");
```

because mother is null. You could change your code into this:

```
Dog mother = getMother(id);
if (mother == null) {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't enough information here. What line are you getting the null pointer on?

if, as I suspect, it's here:

```
MyFrame.jta.append(mother.toString() + "\n");
```

Then you need to determine, through debugging, that it's definitely *mother* that is null. If you have done that, then you can be absolutely positive that your getMother(id); returns null, for the id that you are passing in.

If I were you I would create a unit test for the getMother(id) method and pass in the id that is causing the failure.

If you don't know what id value is causing the problem, then at the very least stick in some System.out.print() statement to find out what is going on. Although, you'd be better using some logging framework, such as log4j.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

Its because your exception is at `mother.toString()` method..

try this

```
try
{
 MyFrame.jta.append(mother.toString() + "\n");
}catch(NullPointerException ignore){}
```

Comment: It's better to check `if(mother != null)` instead of catching and ignoring the exception. Performance, readability, ...